# How to fix ESLint error (prefer-destructuring)

Tags: eslint, destructuring

For the following snippet of code I got the ESLint error, but using their docs, I couldn't find the solution for it.

```
 Object.keys(response).forEach((key) => {
     results[key] = response[key][0]; // <- This line :)
 });
```

The error I get:

`ESLint: Use Array Destructuring. (prefer-destructuring)`

Comment: Are you trying to assign the values at position zero in the array to the response key? Why not use map?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the answer to your specific question, but here are two docs that should get you on your way.

You can read the detail about the rule prefer-destructuring at https://eslint.org/docs/rules/prefer-destructuring.

Also a little reading on destructuring at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Answer (score 0):

You may use that code to not get the error:

```js
Object.keys(response).forEach((key) => {
    [results[key]] = response[key]; // <- This line :)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on an official document from [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)
The object and array literal expressions provide an easy way to create ad hoc packages of data.

```
const x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
```

The destructuring assignment uses similar syntax, but on the left-hand side of the assignment to define what values to unpack from the sourced variable.

```
const x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const [y, z] = x;
console.log(y); // 1
console.log(z); // 2
```

Similarly, you can destructure objects on the left-hand side of the assignment.

```
const obj = { a: 1, b: 2 };
const { a, b } = obj;
// is equivalent to:
// const a = obj.a;
// const b = obj.b;
```